# Execute jQuery code after initializing a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a jQuery snippet after I initialize a custom jQuery plugin.

The snippet needs to modify part of the DOM that the plugin makes, so I need to ensure that the snippet executes after the plugin finishes initializing its DOM.

```
$(function() {
        // initializing the plugin
        PluginConstructor({
                "id": "plugin-container"
        });

        // snippet
        $('.some-div-inside-plugin-container').remove();    
});
```

The above seems to execute non-sequentially, top to bottom, since the snippet has no effect, leading me to believe the snippet was executed before the plugin's DOM has finished initializing.

Is there a jQuery/javascript method that allows the snippet to wait for the completion of the plugin?

I cannot modify the source code of the plugin, by the way.

Comment: And the plugin is.... ???? A phantom??? Maybe the plugin have got any event handler to manage this. Something like `$('selector').on('plugin:ready')`

Comment: Maybe, I will try to find out

Comment: If you don't specify to us what plugin is or what code do you are trying to use, this topic should be marked as should be closed, because too broad, unclear what you're asking, etc.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was an universal way of waiting for a constructor to finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no, there's no `jQuery/javascript` method do that, because that depend to the plugin itself, so you have to check in the plugin you want to use for this function triggred after load (ready status).

Just like example @Marcos mentioned in comment for `phantomJS` we found `onLoadFinished` or `onInitialized` functions.

Comment: Ok I will try to find a similar on load finish method for the plugin